# Cron job for upload s3 object with the large size

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

Recently I've got the trouble with uploading the large database backup file (~80GB) to s3.

```
upload failed: - to s3://<> 'Connection aborted.', BrokenPipeError(32, 'Broken pipe')
```

After trying with option `--expected-size 107374182400` (100GB =107374182400 Bytes ) in s3 cp command, I can upload it. So, I modified the cron job script. I suppose that when the database backup is larger than 100GB, I have to modify its value again. How can I optimize that solution?

Cronjob script

```
mongodump --archive --gzip --authenticationDatabase admin \
        --db db -u mongobackup \
        2> $LOG_FILE \
    | aws s3 cp --storage-class=STANDARD_IA - "s3://$BUCKET/$BACKUP_NAME" --expected-size 107374182400 2> $LOG_FILE_S3
```

Refer: [https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html#:~:text=Uploading%20a%20local%20file%20stream%20that%20is%20larger%20than%2050GB%20to%20S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html#:%7E:text=Uploading%20a%20local%20file%20stream%20that%20is%20larger%20than%2050GB%20to%20S3)

Best Regards,

Comment: What do you mean by "I've got the trouble with uploading the large file"? What happens?

Comment: Hi @JohnRotenstein, you know the database will become bigger in the future and I need to specify the expected-size again. How I can optimize that?

Comment: The `Broken pipe` error is typically caused by a network quality problem, and the larger the upload the more likely it might happen. I'd recommend just trying it again -- it has nothing to do with the `--expected-size` parameter.

Comment: Hi @JohnRotenstein, Actually the cron job (daily) used to backup and upload the database started being failed since the beginning of this month.

Comment: Did it fail _every_ time since the first failure, or just randomly? From where is the upload being sent -- is it on an Amazon EC2 instance, your own computer, or a server in a data center?

Comment: They're all failed. The job is on a ec2 instance. We did succeed before Oct 28, 2022 with the size 78.1 GB.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249803/discussion-between-duyl97-and-john-rotenstein).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script you have shown is outputting data to `stdout` and the AWS CLI is copying it to S3 from `stdin` (as indicated by the `-` source name).

This is coming through as a **stream of data** of unknown size (whereas it is easy to determine the size of a file on disk).

From [aws s3 cp — AWS CLI Command Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html#:%7E:text=Uploading%20a%20local%20file%20stream%20that%20is%20larger%20than%2050GB%20to%20S3):

> `--expected-size (string)` This argument specifies the expected size of a stream in terms of bytes. Note that this argument is **needed only when a stream is being uploaded to s3 and the size is larger than 50GB**. Failure to include this argument under these conditions may result in a failed upload due to too many parts in upload.

Therefore, this value is **required to provide a 'hint'** as to how large the data will be and, therefore, the size of each 'part' being uploaded.

I suspect that it would be okay to provide a number that is too big (eg twice the size), so I would recommend **supplying a number that is definitely bigger than the known size**. You would need to increase it in future as your data grows in size. (Therefore, perhaps even try a number that is 10x the necessary size?)